# searchview returns blank when I search

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new to Xcode and Swift but the understanding is coming. The problem right now is that I have a table view with a searchview in it. When I run the code, data is received from the api to the tableview correctly but when I try to make a search then its returns an empty list.

How can I correct my code?

My Controller:

```
 var clientDetails = [Client]()
var currentClientDetails = [Client]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentClientDetails.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clients_list") as? ClientCellTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.nameLb.text = "Name: " + currentClientDetails[indexPath.row].CLNT_FULLNAME
    cell.emailLb.text = "Email: " + currentClientDetails[indexPath.row].CLNT_EMAIL
    cell.phonenumberLb.text = "Phone Number: " + currentClientDetails[indexPath.row].CLNT_PHONE
    cell.clientidLb.text = "ID: " + currentClientDetails[indexPath.row].CLNT_CODE
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.clientsTableView.delegate = self
    self.clientsTableView.dataSource = self

    fetchData()
    setUpSearchBar()
    alterLayout()
}

func alterLayout() {
    clientsTableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
    // search bar in section header
    clientsTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50
    // search bar in navigation bar
    //navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = false // you can show/hide this dependant on your layout
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search Client by Name"
}

private func setUpSearchBar() {
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func fetchData(){

    let myapiurl = URL(string: "https://fpay.com/api")

    guard let downloadURL = myapiurl else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Fofoofo Pay", message: "Please try again or check your internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(action)

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }
        print("JSON downloaded")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedJson = try decoder.decode(Client_details.self, from: data)
            self.clientDetails = downloadedJson.client_details
            self.currentClientDetails = self.clientDetails
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.clientsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}

  // Search Bar
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ client -> Bool in
            switch searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex {
            case 0:
                if searchText.isEmpty { return true }
                return client.CLNT_FULLNAME.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            default:
                return false
            }
        })
        clientsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Client class:

```
    Client_details: Codable {
    let client_details: [Client]

    init(client_details: [Client]) {
        self.client_details = client_details
    }
}

class Client:Codable {
    let CLNT_CODE:String
    let CLNT_FULLNAME:String
    let CLNT_PHONE:String
    let CLNT_EMAIL:String
    init(CLNT_CODE:String, CLNT_FULLNAME:String, CLNT_PHONE:String, CLNT_EMAIL:String) {
        self.CLNT_CODE = CLNT_CODE
        self.CLNT_FULLNAME = CLNT_FULLNAME
        self.CLNT_PHONE = CLNT_PHONE
        self.CLNT_EMAIL = CLNT_EMAIL
    }
```

Comment: Do you want this to search case-sensitive, case-insensitive, partial match, match beginning, or match ending? From what I can tell right now you're attempting to filter your `clientDetails` and store the result in `currentClientDetails` however there is no comparison taking place to create a proper return value.

Comment: @xTwisteDx yes please i wish to have search case-sensitive, case-insensitive, partial match, match beginning, and match ending. Im new on swift. I dont know how to go by it.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the case 0: section, is it getting to the if searchTxt.isEmpty line?  Also, if you put a break point at the end of the function at clientsTableView.reloadData(), what does currentClientDetails look like?

Comment: `currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ $0.contains(searchText.lowercased()})`

Comment: @xTwisteDx thank you but look at my question, ive updated it. I honestly dont know what to do with what you just sent. With all humility Sir

Comment: @HalR Please have a look at my question, ive updated it.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in there to check and ensure that you're even hitting that code-block? Place the breakpoint inside the case statement. Also try using `searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty`

Comment: Problem solved Brothers, thank you. Solution is here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. I changed the code in my searchBar function to this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        currentClientDetails = clientDetails
        if searchText.isEmpty == false {
        currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ $0.CLNT_FULLNAME.contains(searchText) })
        }

        clientsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

It now returns only the ones searched- It is case-sensitive, case-insensitive, partial match, match beginning, and match ending. Also when search field is empty it shows all the data.

Comment: That's literally the same thing that my solution provided... `currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ $0.contains(searchText.lowercased()})` except that mine will check any matches, yours will only check the leading matches.

Comment: i get error at `contains` when i use it. is there a solution? @xTwisteDx

Comment: I think I have my {} in the wrong spot. I don't have XCode available at the moment. Try removing the ().

Comment: `currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ $0.CLNT_FULLNAME.contains(searchText) })`

Thank you for the inspiration @xTwisteDx. My problem is totally solved

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to take an opportunity to give you a breakdown of what's happening so that you can continue to learn and bolster your skills. So the issue that you're having is that your `searchBar(_ textDidChange:...)` method is not filtering the way you're expecting. Particularly this block of code.

```
currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ client -> Bool in
        switch searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex {
        case 0:
            if searchText.isEmpty { return true }
            return client.CLNT_FULLNAME.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        default:
            return false
        }
    })
```

There are two possible reasons this is not producing anything. Reason #1, your `client.CLNT_FULLNAME` is returning `""` or your method is always returning false because the first element is `""` or hitting `default:` which returns false.

Based on the code that you've provided `client` is never sequenced. Meaning it's always the same thing every single time the `searchBar(_ textDidChange:...)` method is hit, never changes inside of your closure. So to fix this let's break down the solution.

#### Solution

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        currentClientDetails = clientDetails.filter({ $0.CLNT_FULLNAME.contains(searchText) })
        clientsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

So, what's happening inside of this closure vs what you have? What exactly does `.filter()` do, and how does that closure work? There are two versions of `.filter()` and in your case, you're using a sequential closure. That means that it will return an `[object]` based on a given predicate (Formula).

What is the predicate given here and what's that fancy `$0` all about? The predicate given in the `.filter()` is checking each element in your `[object]` and returning true or false for each element. True if it contains some or all of a match, or false if not. Once the closure completes, or the **sequence** completes, it returns a given object. In your case, it appears to be a `[client]`.

I like to consider the `.filter()` method as a sort of `for _ in 0..X` loop and this is an important concept to consider when you are using those aforementioned `$0` fancy-looking things. Essentially that `$0` is saying the first element in the sequence compared to what? or `client[0]` compared to what. That would be the initial sequence and it will continue until the sequence is completed, aka the count of the `for _ in 0...X.count`.

I hope that this gives you something to consider and allows you to continue coding. Thank you for posting a thoughtful question and being actively engaged while working through the problem.

Comment: Awesome `halfer` you just made my day! Thanks so so much!